# Dimension formula $\dim_x(X) = \dim(S_p)+\text{trdeg}_ k\ \kappa (\mathfrak p)$ from The Stacks project

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have a question about the proof of  [Lemma 10.116.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00P1)  from The Stacks project. The claim is:

**Lemma 10.116.3.** Let $k$ be a field. Let $S$ be a finite type
$k$ algebra.
Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}(S)$. Let $\mathfrak p \subset S$ be a prime ideal,
and let $x \in X$ be the corresponding point. Then we have
$$\dim_x(X) = \dim(S_p)+\text{trdeg}_ k\  \kappa (\mathfrak p).$$

**Proof.** By Lemma 10.116.1 we know that
$r= \text{trdeg}_ k\  \kappa (\mathfrak p)$ is equal to
the dimension of $V(\mathfrak p)$. Pick any maximal chain of primes
$ \mathfrak p \subset \mathfrak p_1 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak p_ r $
starting with $p$ in $S$. This has length $r$ by Lemma 10.114.4.
Let $q_j, j \in J$ be the minimal primes of $S$ which are
contained in $p$.
These correspond 1−1 to minimal primes in the localization $S_p$
via the rule $\mathfrak q_ j \mapsto \mathfrak q_ jS_{\mathfrak p}$.
By Lemma 10.114.5 we know that
$\dim_x(X)$ is equal to the maximum of the dimensions of the
rings $S/q_j$. For each $j$ pick a maximal chain of primes
$\mathfrak q_ j \subset \mathfrak p'_1 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak p'_{s(j)} = \mathfrak p$.
Then $\dim (S_{\mathfrak p})=\max _{j \in J} s(j)$. Now, each chain

$$ \mathfrak q_ i \subset \mathfrak p'_1 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak p'_{s(j)} = \mathfrak p \subset \mathfrak p_1 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak p_ r   $$

is a maximal chain in $S/\mathfrak q_ j$, and by what was said before we
have $ \dim _ x(X) = \max _{j \in J} r + s(j) $. The lemma follows.

**Question:** Why the constructed prime ideals chain

$$ \mathfrak q_ i \subset \mathfrak p'_1 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak p'_{s(j)} = \mathfrak p \subset \mathfrak p_1 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak p_ r   $$

is maximal in $S/\mathfrak q_ j$. Or in other words why every *maximal*
prime chain in $S/\mathfrak q_ j$ should contain $\mathfrak p$
as an intermediete chain member. That is I not see any reason why for an *arbitrary* $k$ algebra $R$ and prime $p \subset R$ there should be hold $\dim(R)= \dim(R_p)+ \dim(R/p)$. $S$ and $S/\mathfrak q_ j$ were not assumed
to be catenary rings or do I miss something.

Adds: I know that there is a bunch of books on cummutative algebra containing a different proof of this claim but my motivation here is to understand the step in this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the question: A finite type $k$-algebra that is a domain, is catenary. The reference for this statement is Matsumura, Commutative Algebra, Chapter 5, (14.H).

So every maximal chain of prime ideals in $S/\mathfrak{q_j}$ has the same length.

Comment: But why, if $\mathfrak{q}_j $ is contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ this implies that for *every* maximal chain of prime ideals $\mathfrak q_ i \subset \mathfrak p_1  \subset \mathfrak p_2 \subset ...  \subset \mathfrak p_r $ starting with $\mathfrak q_ i$ there exist an intermadiate member $\mathfrak{p}_i$ with $p_i=\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: @katalaveino I realized that the earlier post didn't address your question. I have added the required reference. It might happen that not every maximal chain of prime ideals starting with $\mathfrak{q}_j$ contains $\mathfrak{p}$ at the intermediate term.